# Как исправить выход блока за пределы родительского?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок, который сделан по виду как тень для кнопки, но он выходит за пределы самого большого блока. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Верстка:

```css
div#login {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: #b8c783;
}

div#form {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

p#easy_chat {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  color: #fffecd;
}

div#register {
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

p.name_password {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: #635960;
}

input.login {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fffecd;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: #635960;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

div#shadow {
  width: 312px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(-5deg, #b8c783, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  transform: matrix(1, -0.13, 0.5, 1.2, 50, 0);
}

input#submit {
  width: 312px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: #635960;
  color: #fffecd;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <div id="forms">
    <p id="easy_chat">Easy Chat</p>
    <div id="register">
      <form method="POST">
        <p class="name_password">Enter your name</p>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="login">

        <p class="name_password">Enter your pasword</p>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="login">
      </form>
    </div>
    <input type="Submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    <div id="shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить `overflow: hidden;` родительскому контейнеру `div#login`.

```css
div#login {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #b8c783;
}

div#form {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

p#easy_chat {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  color: #fffecd;
}

div#register {
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

p.name_password {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: #635960;
}

input.login {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fffecd;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: #635960;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

div#shadow {
  width: 312px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(-5deg, #b8c783, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  transform: matrix(1, -0.13, 0.5, 1.2, 50, 0);
}

input#submit {
  width: 312px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: #635960;
  color: #fffecd;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <div id="forms">
    <p id="easy_chat">Easy Chat</p>
    <div id="register">
      <form method="POST">
        <p class="name_password">Enter your name</p>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="login">

        <p class="name_password">Enter your pasword</p>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="login">
      </form>
    </div>
    <input type="Submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    <div id="shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё сработало как нужно)

Answer (score 2):

Для своей тени задай css свойство:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Не для тени, а для родительского контейнера тени. Применяя свойство для тени в данном случае ничего не произойдет.